# How to revert an old pull request in a new branch

Tags: git, github

How do I revert a pull request in a new branch? Or do I need to revert every commit by its hash?

Context: there have been many other PRs merged with `develop` since the one I want to revert, so I want to test the revert first (in a new branch) before making the changes in my `develop` branch.

Comment: You should be able to revert a whole PR, but if another branch depends on it in some way it won’t be simple.

Answer (score 0):

Very basically, yes, you'd have to create a new branch from your current reference branch, `develop` I guess, then revert here, in reverse chronological order, the set of commits which were brought in by said past PR.

Let's postulate this tree to help our reasonning :

```
A---B---------C---D---E <<< develop
     \       /
      B1---B2 <<< branch-1
```

and you want to revert the old "branch-1 > develop" PR which brought commits `B1` and `B2`.

Then

```
git checkout -b new-branch-1 develop
git revert B2 B1
# at this point you might have conflicts to resolve, then commit if needed.
```

Although, beware of other merge commits, because as evolutionbox rightfully [warned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57953839/how-to-revert-an-old-pull-request-in-a-new-branch#comment102319994_57953839) about, it will be a lot more messy if other branches are involved.

Answer (score 0):

Simply mark the hash by using

> `git log`

the exit the log by pressing

> `q`

Now type

> `git checkout <your previous commit hash>`
>
> `git checkout -b <new branch name>`

you will get the code in new branch.

Comment: As a sidenote, you can have your two last steps with `git checkout -b <newBranch> <previousCommitHash>`. But mainly : how is this gonna revert the PR Sam is refering to? I admit it's a good start to spot the hash of commits to revert, but you're not done yet...